# what is the overhead of wrapping primitives as objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, gwt

What, if any, overhead is incurred by wrapping primitive JavaScript values so they become objects?

For example:

```
> var x = Object(12);
undefined
> typeof x
"object"
> ({}).toString.call(x);
"[object Number]"
```

vs

```
> var y = 12;
undefined
> typeof y
"number"
> ({}).toString.call(y);
"[object Number]"
```

---

My reason for asking:  I'm working with GWT code that transforms values between JavaScript and Java code (which is later compiled into Javascript code).  Since Java cares a lot about types and GWT JSNI (the interop method) supports primitives and objects, I was wondering why not just return 'boxed' primitives (eg Object(12) is a boxed version of 12).

The answer is what I expected clear - speed.  I didn't realize it would be so severe, but clearly avoid boxed Javascript primitives if you can or pay a serious price in performance.  (with the caveat that overhead from method calls flips this around as Jan mentions)

Comment: There's a great writeup on the subject of primitives vs objects: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var x = Object(12);` appears to be about 97% slower than `var x = 12;`

http://jsperf.com/object-wrap-number-overhead

However, if you intend to call a method on the number, the difference is far less, though still faster to *not* call `Object()` on the number.

---

But the real question is why are you doing this? You can call methods on numbers without this explicit transformation.

```
var x = 12.1234;
x.toFixed(2); // "12.12"
```

Comment: awesome - thanks.  and now we're getting some data from different browsers.

Comment: The overhead from calling methods on primitives is excessive, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Primitives are not objects, so they are less expensive (see the Alex Wayne's answer). On the other hand

> You can call any of the methods of the String object on a string literal value—JavaScript automatically converts the string literal to a temporary String object, calls the method, then discards the temporary String object. You can also use the String.length property with a string literal.

[see the MDN manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals)

So use primitives, but if you want to call methods on them, you should create object instead.

Comment: thanks - but my question is what is the overhead, not when to use them.

Comment: well, the overhead is gross, as Wayne says in his answer. However, if you use methods, it is bigger overhead if you DON'T create object.